# ModuleWithProviders generic type for Angular 10 Projects?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

`ModuleWithProviders` now requires a generic type argument.

For the below module what would be the correct argument.  I assume `MaterialModule`?

```
export class MaterialModule {
    constructor(public matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry) {
         matIconRegistry.registerFontClassAlias('fontawesome', 'fa');
    }

    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: MaterialModule,
            providers: [MatIconRegistry]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assumed right, 99.9% of the time it's the same module, at least in the `forRoot` method.

```
static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<MaterialModule> {
    return {
        ngModule: MaterialModule,
        providers: [MatIconRegistry]
    }
}
```

It's mainly used for dynamic module loader